# Nested Components: How to pass data item from a component using *ngFor to another component which uses recursion?

Tags: html, angular, nested, angular8, angular-components

I created my own custom element with the DropdownMenuTreeComponent to use inside another component as < dropdown-menu-tree > and I pass it a nodeTree which is an array of nodes:

```
nodeTree: Array<Node> = [];
Node = { Name:String, Children:Array<Node> }
```

Then, inside the DropdownMenuTreeComponent I try to pass a single node from my Array nodeTree to my NodesRendererComponent as I call it from inside the template of DropDownMenuTreeComponent with < nodes-rendered > and I pass it a "node" from nodeTree.

The issue here is that when I run the code while DropdownMenuTreeComponent is able to get the nodeTree from the 1st component it is nested( DropdownMenuTreeComponent being the 2nd component) it is not able to pass it to NodesRendererComponent as node.Name appears as undefined but I can see the "This works!" text in the screen.

I need this 3 levels of components because I need my NodesRendererComponent to be recursive and other aspects not relevant right now. So, what am I doing wrong or how can I make the NodesRendererComponent get each node from nodeTree while also being able to recurse?

DropdownMenuTreeComponent (Nested component #2):

```
 @Component({
   template: `<div>  
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu-tree">
                    <li *ngFor="let node of nodeTree">
                       <nodes-renderer  [node]="node"></nodes-renderer>
                    </li>
                   </ul>
              </div>`,
   styleUrls: ['./dropdown-menu-tree.component.css']
 })

 export class DropdownMenuTreeComponent implements OnInit{
   @Input() nodeTree: any[];

   constructor() {}

   ngOnInit(){}

 }
```

NodesRendererComponent (Nested Component #3):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'nodes-renderer',
  template: ` {{node.Name }}
              <p> This Works! </p>
              <li *ngFor="let node of node.Children">
              <nodes-renderer [node]="node"></nodes-renderer>`
    ,
})

export class NodesRendererComponent implements OnInit{
  @Input() node: any;

  constructor() { 

  }
  ngOnInit(){
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the optional chaining operator: `{{node?.Name}}`?

Comment: What happens if you put {{node | json}} below this works?

Comment: @julianobrasil This was what I was missing!

Comment: @tuckerjt07 I was able to see all the node attributes, I was just missing the optional chaining operator. Thanks this is useful for the future.